# NXT sensors and ROS

Tags: ros, nxt, nxt-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What are the possible ways to use NXT sensors such as light sensor, IR and Compass?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10521/nxt-sensors-and-ros/) by [Nirali](https://answers.ros.org/users/802/nirali/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-07-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

check out the example robots for ideas: http://www.ros.org/wiki/nxt_robots

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2